# Different Unique number for each thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I am running the below code for 60 minutes and what it is doing is that each thread will use different Unique ID basis on whether command has Previous or not. If it is Previous, then it will use existing ID in between 1 and 1000 and If it is not Previous then it will use unique ID in between 5000 and 10000. I wrote this code in which If command has Previous then each thread will use unique ID in between 1 and 1000 and if it is not Previous then it will use unique ID in between 5000 and 10000.

**So Problem Statement is like this-
If command has Previous, then each thread will use unique ID in between 1 and 1000
And If it is not Previous, then each thread will use Unique ID in between 5000 and 10000**

**My Question is- 
1) This is the right way to do it? Or what can be the best way
2) Secondly this is really very slow, It gets stop at sometimes and it doesn't use any Unique ID in between those numbers. and I need to reuse the id also if id the is finished**

```
class IdPool {
    private final LinkedList<Integer> availableExistingIds = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    private final LinkedList<Integer> availableNewIds = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    public IdPool() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
            availableExistingIds.add(i);
        }

        for (int k = 5000; k <=10000; k++) {
            availableNewIds.add(k);
        }
    }

    public synchronized Integer getNewId() {
        return availableNewIds.removeFirst();
    }

    public synchronized void releaseNewId(Integer id) {
        availableNewIds.add(id);
    }

    public synchronized Integer getExistingId() {
        return availableExistingIds.removeFirst();
    }

    public synchronized void releaseExistingId(Integer id) {
        availableExistingIds.add(id);
    }
}


class ThreadNewTask implements Runnable {
    private IdPool idPool;
    private Command command;

    public ThreadNewTask(IdPool idPool, Command cmd) {
        this.idPool = idPool;
        this.command = cmd;
    }

    public void run() {
        if(command.getDataCriteria().equals("Previous")) {
            Integer id = idPool.getExistingId();
            newMethod(id);
            idPool.releaseExistingId(id);
        } else {
            Integer newId = idPool.getNewId();
            newMethod(newId);
            idPool.releaseExistingId(newId);
        }

    }

    private void newMethod(Integer i) {
        System.out.println("Task ID: " +i);

    }
}

public class TestingPool {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        int size = 10;
        int durationOfRun = 60;
        IdPool idPool = new IdPool();   
        // create thread pool with given size
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(size); 

        // queue some tasks
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long endTime = startTime + (durationOfRun * 60 * 1000L);

        // Running it for 60 minutes
        while(System.currentTimeMillis() <= endTime) {
            Command nextCommand = getNextCommandToExecute();
            service.submit(new ThreadNewTask(idPool, nextCommand));
        }

        // wait for termination        
        service.shutdown();
        service.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.DAYS); 
    }
}
```

Comment: as long as you synchronize all data access/modification, each thread will be assigned a unique number.

Comment: Why don't you say what particularly you are worried about? I'd put that acquire-release id segment in a try-finally to ensure that each acquired id is released. I don't see any other major wrongdoings. If you want more performance, study the [`BlockingDeque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingDeque.html) from java.util.concurrent. If you use it, you won't need the `synchronized` kewyord at all.

Comment: Don't threads have a unique ID already?  `Thread.currentThread().getId()`?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, Can you give me example on that basis on my code, That will be of great help to me, as I haven't worked with that before.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, ID has to be in that range 1 - 1000 for existing id and 5000 to 10000 for new ID's

Comment: @LouisWasserman The threads are pooled and OP needs task id's.

Comment: OP, why don't you study that Javadoc page for a while. I don't think it's going to take you very long to get around.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, Yes that is right. Any example will be appreciated in which if Command is Previous then use unique id between 1 and 1000 and if it is not previous use unique ID from 5000-10000.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, I tried going thru but not able to figure it out, how I can do that. And one more thing in the run method the way I have put if else block is right? Or we can make that more accurate?